# How do I pass secret value from keyvault using Azure ARM Template

Tags: json, azure, azure-rm-template

I am trying to create Azure Application Gateway with ssl certificate from keyvaults. But didn't find any option to add keyvaults to ARM template with .pfx and .cer files. So I have encoded the certificate contents and added as secret in existing keyvault. Now trying to pass the secrets using ARM template. Validation passed but getting error in Deployment stage. Attached the template and parameters I am using.

Getting Error while deploying the resource

```
Deployment template validation failed: 'Template parameter JToken type is not valid. Expected 'String, Uri'. Actual 'Object'
  "additionalInfo": [
    {
      "type": "TemplateViolation",
      "info": {
        "lineNumber": 226,
        "linePosition": 33,
        "path": "properties.template.parameters.appgwfesslcertsecret"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Updated Template:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "namingSettings": {
        "type": "object"
      },
      "taggingSettings": {
        "type": "object"
      },
      "applicationGatewaySettings": {
        "type": "object"
      },
      "appgwfesslcertsecret": {
        "type": "securestring"
      },
      "appgwbecertsecret": {
        "type": "securestring"
      }
    },
    "variables": {
      "namePrefix": "[concat(parameters('namingSettings').name.org,'-',parameters('namingSettings').name.cloud,'-',parameters('namingSettings').name.region,'-',parameters('namingSettings').name.businessUnit,'-',parameters('namingSettings').name.account,'-',parameters('namingSettings').name.app,'-',parameters('namingSettings').name.sdlc,'-')]"    },
    "resources": [
      {
        "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
        "name": "[concat(variables('namePrefix'),parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].name)]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "copy": {
          "name": "appgwCopy",
          "count": "[length(parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings)]"
        },
        "tags": "[parameters('taggingSettings').tags]",
        "properties": {
          "sku": {
            "name": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].applicationGatewaySku]",
            "tier": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].applicationGatewayTier]",
            "capacity": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].applicationGatewayInstanceCount]"
          },
          "sslPolicy": {
            "policyType": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].policyType]",
            "policyName": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].policy]"
          },
          "copy": [
            {
              "name": "frontendPorts",
              "count": "[length(parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].frontendPorts)]",
              "input": {
                "name": "[concat(variables('namePrefix'),parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].frontendPorts[copyIndex('frontendPorts')].name)]",
                "properties": {
                  "port": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].frontendPorts[copyIndex('frontendPorts')].properties.port]"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "gatewayIPConfigurations",
              "count": "[length(parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].gatewayIPConfigurations)]",
              "input": {
                "name": "[concat(variables('namePrefix'),parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].gatewayIPConfigurations[copyIndex('gatewayIPConfigurations')].name)]",
                "properties": {
                  "subnet": {
                    "id": "[resourceId(parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].gatewayIPConfigurations[copyIndex('gatewayIPConfigurations')].properties.subnet.vnetRGName,'microsoft.network/virtualnetworks/subnets', parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].gatewayIPConfigurations[copyIndex('gatewayIPConfigurations')].properties.subnet.vnetName, parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].gatewayIPConfigurations[copyIndex('gatewayIPConfigurations')].properties.subnet.subnetName)]"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "frontendIPConfigurations",
              "count": "[length(parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].frontendIPConfigurations)]",
              "input": {
                "name": "[concat(variables('namePrefix'),parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].frontendIPConfigurations[copyIndex('frontendIPConfigurations')].name)]",
                "properties": {
                  "subnet": {
                    "id": "[resourceId(parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].gatewayIPConfigurations[copyIndex('frontendIPConfigurations')].properties.subnet.vnetRGName,'microsoft.network/virtualnetworks/subnets', parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].frontendIPConfigurations[copyIndex('frontendIPConfigurations')].properties.subnet.vnetName, parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].frontendIPConfigurations[copyIndex('frontendIPConfigurations')].properties.subnet.subnetName)]"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "backendHttpSettingsCollection",
              "count": "[length(parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].backendHttpSettingsCollection)]",
              "input": {
                "name": "[concat(variables('namePrefix'),parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].backendHttpSettingsCollection[copyIndex('backendHttpSettingsCollection')].name)]",
                "properties": {
                  "port": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].backendHttpSettingsCollection[copyIndex('backendHttpSettingsCollection')].properties.port]",
                  "protocol": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].backendHttpSettingsCollection[copyIndex('backendHttpSettingsCollection')].properties.protocol]",
                  "authenticationCertificates": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].backendHttpSettingsCollection[copyIndex('backendHttpSettingsCollection')].properties.authenticationCertificates]"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "backendAddressPools",
              "count": "[length(parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].backendAddressPools)]",
              "input": {
                "name": "[concat(variables('namePrefix'),parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].backendAddressPools[copyIndex('backendAddressPools')].name)]"
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "httpListeners",
              "count": "[length(parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].httpListeners)]",
              "input": {
                "name": "[concat(variables('namePrefix'),parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].httpListeners[copyIndex('httpListeners')].name)]",
                "properties": {
                  "frontendIPConfiguration": {
                    "id": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'microsoft.network/applicationGateways/frontendIPConfigurations', concat(variables('namePrefix'),parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].name),concat(variables('namePrefix'), parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].httpListeners[copyIndex('httpListeners')].properties.frontendIPConfiguration))]"
                  },
                  "frontendPort": {
                    "id": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'microsoft.network/applicationGateways/frontendPorts', concat(variables('namePrefix'),parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].name),concat(variables('namePrefix'), parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].httpListeners[copyIndex('httpListeners')].properties.frontendPort))]"
                  },
                  "protocol": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].httpListeners[copyIndex('httpListeners')].properties.protocol]",
                  "sslCertificate": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].httpListeners[copyIndex('httpListeners')].properties.sslCertificate]"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "requestRoutingRules",
              "count": "[length(parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].requestRoutingRules)]",
              "input": {
                "name": "[concat(variables('namePrefix'),parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].requestRoutingRules[copyIndex('requestRoutingRules')].name)]",
                "properties": {
                  "httpListener": {
                    "id": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'microsoft.network/applicationGateways/httpListeners', concat(variables('namePrefix'),parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].name),concat(variables('namePrefix'), parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].requestRoutingRules[copyIndex('requestRoutingRules')].properties.httpListener))]"
                  },
                  "backendAddressPool": {
                    "id": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'microsoft.network/applicationGateways/backendAddressPools', concat(variables('namePrefix'),parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].name),concat(variables('namePrefix'), parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].requestRoutingRules[copyIndex('requestRoutingRules')].properties.backendAddressPool))]"
                  },
                  "backendHttpSettings": {
                    "id": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'microsoft.network/applicationGateways/backendHttpSettingsCollection', concat(variables('namePrefix'),parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].name),concat(variables('namePrefix'), parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].requestRoutingRules[copyIndex('requestRoutingRules')].properties.backendHttpSettings))]"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
                "name": "sslCertificates",
                "count": "[length(parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].sslCertificates)]",
                "input": {
                  "name": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].sslCertificates[copyIndex('sslCertificates')].name]",
                  "properties": {
                    "data": "[parameters('appgwfesslcertsecret')]",
                    "password": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].sslCertificates[copyIndex('sslCertificates')].properties.password]"
                  }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "authenticationCertificates",
                "count": "[length(parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].authenticationCertificates)]",
                "input": {
                  "name": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].authenticationCertificates[copyIndex('authenticationCertificates')].name]",
                  "properties": {
                    "data": "[parameters('appgwbecertsecret')]"
                  }
                }
            }
          ],
          "probes": [],
          "webApplicationFirewallConfiguration": {
            "enabled": true,
            "firewallMode": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].firewallMode]",
            "ruleSetType": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].ruleSetType]",
            "ruleSetVersion": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].ruleSetVersion]",
            "requestBodyCheck": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].requestBodyCheck]",
            "maxRequestBodySizeInKb": "[if(parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].requestBodyCheck, parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].maxReqBodySize, json('null'))]",
            "fileUploadLimitInMb": "[int(100)]"
          },
          "enableHttp2": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].enableHTTP2]"
        },
        "resources": [
          {
            "type": "providers/diagnosticSettings",
            "name": "[concat('Microsoft.Insights/', parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].diagname)]",
            "dependsOn": [
              "[concat(variables('namePrefix'),parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].name)]"
            ],
            "apiVersion": "2017-05-01-preview",
            "properties": {
              "name": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].diagname]",
              "logs": [
                {
                  "category": "ApplicationGatewayAccessLog",
                  "enabled": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].enableApplicationGatewayAccessLog]",
                  "retentionPolicy": {
                    "days": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].applicationGatewayAccessLogRetentionDays]",
                    "enabled": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].enableApplicationGatewayAccessLogRetention]"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "category": "ApplicationGatewayPerformanceLog",
                  "enabled": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].enableApplicationGatewayPerformanceLog]",
                  "retentionPolicy": {
                    "days": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].applicationGatewayPerformanceLogRetentionDays]",
                    "enabled": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].enableApplicationGatewayPerformanceLogRetention]"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "category": "ApplicationGatewayFirewallLog",
                  "enabled": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].enableApplicationGatewayFirewallLog]",
                  "retentionPolicy": {
                    "days": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].applicationGatewayFirewallLogRetentionDays]",
                    "enabled": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].enableApplicationGatewayFirewallLogRetention]"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "metrics": [
                {
                  "category": "AllMetrics",
                  "enabled": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].enableAllMetrics]",
                  "retentionPolicy": {
                    "enabled": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].enableAllMetricsRetentionPolicy]",
                    "days": "[parameters('applicationGatewaySettings').settings[copyIndex('appgwCopy')].allMetricsRetentionDays]"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
  }
```

Updated Parameter File:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "namingSettings": {
            "value": {
                "name": {
                    "app": "demo",
                    "cloud": "azu",
                    "region": "eus2",

                }
            }
        },
        "taggingSettings": {
            "value": {
                "tags": {
                    "AppID": "demo",
                    "Environment": "nonprod",

                }
            }
        },
        "applicationGatewaySettings": {
            "value": {
                "settings": [
                    {
                        "name": "appgw-pcs01",
                        "applicationGatewaySku": "WAF_Medium",
                        "applicationGatewayTier": "WAF",
                        "applicationGatewayInstanceCount": 2,
                        "policyType": "Predefined",
                        "policy": "AppGwSslPolicy20170401S",
                        "publicIP": null,
                        "firewallMode": "Prevention",
                        "diagname": "Demo-Appgw",
                        "ruleSetType": "OWASP",
                        "ruleSetVersion": "3.0",
                        "requestBodyCheck": true,
                        "maxReqBodySize": 10,
                        "enableHTTP2": false,
                        "enableApplicationGatewayAccessLog": true,
                        "applicationGatewayAccessLogRetentionDays": 30,
                        "enableApplicationGatewayAccessLogRetention": true,
                        "enableApplicationGatewayPerformanceLog": true,
                        "applicationGatewayPerformanceLogRetentionDays": 30,
                        "enableApplicationGatewayPerformanceLogRetention": true,
                        "enableApplicationGatewayFirewallLog": true,
                        "applicationGatewayFirewallLogRetentionDays": 30,
                        "enableApplicationGatewayFirewallLogRetention": true,
                        "enableAllMetrics": true,
                        "enableAllMetricsRetentionPolicy": true,
                        "allMetricsRetentionDays": 30,
                        "frontendPorts": [
                            {
                                "name": "feport-80",
                                "properties": {
                                    "port": 80
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "feport-443",
                                "properties": {
                                    "port": 443
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "gatewayIPConfigurations": [
                            {
                                "name": "gwipconfig-pcs01",
                                "properties": {
                                    "subnet": {
                                        "vnetName": "demo-vnet",
                                        "vnetRGName": "demo",
                                        "subnetName": "demo-subgw"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "sslCertificates": [
                            {
                                "name": "appgwfesslcert",
                                "properties": {
                                  "data": null,
                                  "password": "password"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "authenticationCertificates": [
                            {
                                "name": "appgwbecert",
                                "properties": {
                                   "data": null
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "frontEndIPConfigurations": [
                            {
                                "name": "feipcfg-pcs01",
                                "properties": {
                                    "subnet": {
                                        "vnetName": "demo-vnet",
                                        "vnetRGName": "demo",
                                        "subnetName": "demo-subgw"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "httpListeners": [
                            {
                                "name": "httplistener-pcs01",
                                "properties": {
                                    "frontendIPConfiguration": "feipcfg-pcs01",
                                    "frontendPort": "feport-80",
                                    "protocol": "Http",
                                    "sslCertificate": {}
                                }
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "httpslistener-pcs01",
                              "properties": {
                                  "frontendIPConfiguration": "feipcfg-pcs01",
                                  "frontendPort": "feport-443",
                                  "protocol": "Https",
                                  "sslCertificate": {
                                    "id": "/subscriptions/105dcee5-gy46-48e3-9046-265c7379e647/resourceGroups/demo/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/azu-eus2-nonprod-appgw-pcs01/sslCertificates/appgwfesslcert"
                                }
                            }
                          }
                        ],
                        "backendHttpSettingsCollection": [
                            {
                                "name": "httpsetcol-default",
                                "properties": {
                                    "protocol": "Http",
                                    "port": 80,
                                    "authenticationCertificates": []
                                }
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "httpssetcol-default",
                              "properties": {
                                  "protocol": "Https",
                                  "port": 443,
                                  "authenticationCertificates": [
                                      {
                                        "id": "/subscriptions/105dcee5-gy46-48e3-9046-265c7379e647/resourceGroups/demo/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/azu-eus2-nonprod-appgw-pcs01/authenticationCertificates/appgwbecert"
                                      }
                                  ]
                              }
                          }
                        ],
                        "backendAddressPools": [
                            {
                                "name": "beap-pcs01"
                            }
                        ],
                        "requestRoutingRules": [
                            {
                                "name": "httpreqrtrule-pcs01",
                                "properties": {
                                    "httpListener": "httplistener-pcs01",
                                    "backendAddressPool": "beap-pcs01",
                                    "backendHttpSettings": "httpsetcol-default"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "httpsreqrtrule-pcs01",
                              "properties": {
                                  "httpListener": "httpslistener-pcs01",
                                  "backendAddressPool": "beap-pcs01",
                                  "backendHttpSettings": "httpssetcol-default"
                              }
                          }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "appgwfesslcertsecret": {
            "value": {
                "reference": {
                  "keyVault": {
                    "id": "/subscriptions/105dcee5-gy46-48e3-9046-265c7379e647/resourceGroups/demo/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/demo-kv-new"
                  },
                  "secretName": "appgwfesslcert"
                }
            }
        },
        "appgwbecertsecret": {
            "value": {
                "reference": {
                  "keyVault": {
                    "id": "/subscriptions/105dcee5-gy46-48e3-9046-265c7379e647/resourceGroups/demo/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/demo-kv-new"
                  },
                  "secretName": "appgwbecert"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can only reference KV secrets in the parameters section of the template (or parameters file). You cannot use it in a random place in the template

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-tutorial-use-key-vault

Comment: I have followed the above document, still getting error

Comment: means you did a mistake somewhere, I'm afraid. can you share the updated template and the parameters file?

Comment: Updated the script.  In parameter while refering the secret without "value" it is not allowing to proceed

Comment: that should be without value, how are you deploying that? [example](https://github.com/4c74356b41/bbbb-is-the-word/blob/master/_arm/parent.json#L151)

Comment: from portal, using custom template

Comment: sure, let me check, Thanks

Comment: hey, did you check it yet, mate?

Comment: Not yet, as still waiting for some information before testing the script.